# Clinical Trial Simulation: Tutorial instructions not correct

Tags: r, simulation, clinical-trials

In the manual of the CT Simulation toolkit `MSToolkit`, a dose-response trial is evaluated using the following code:

```
macroCode <- function(data) {
  # Is effect at highest dose significant?
  success <- data$LOWER[data$INTERIM==max(data$INTERIM) & data$DOSE==max(data$DOSE)] > 7
  data.frame( SUCCESS = success )
}
```

`data` is the trial data, `data$LOWER` is the lower 95 % CI bound of the dose response relative to placebo and `INTERIM` refers to interim analysis being carried out on the subjects (or not). Here, `INTERIM` just makes sure that the result from the final state of the subjects are considered. Regardless, in the [manual](http://mstoolkit.r-forge.r-project.org/analysis_%20simple%20emax%20fit%20example.html), they write:

> The above macro-evaluation is used to assess trial-level success or
>   failure. This code looks at the lower confidence limits of the
>   difference over placebo and if all of these values are less than zero
>   declares the trial a failure. If at least ONE of these confidence
>   limits are above zero then the trial is deemed a success.

I can't follow this. To me, the code says `for the last INTERIM and the maximum DOSE, if the lower limit of the CI is arbitrarily greater than 7, the trial is a success`.

Why did they write what they wrote? It just doesn't agree in my opinion.